# Create table in MySQL Connector/C++ in the proper way (without using query)

Tags: c++, mysql

I want to use MySQL Connector/C++ DevAPI to create a table.

I have written this code.

```
#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>

std::string query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + std::string(tableName) + " (" + columNames + ")";
mysqlx::SqlResult result = connection->sql(query).execute();
return result.getWarningsCount() == 0 ? MYSQL_STATUS_OK : MYSQL_STATUS_FAIL;
```

Sure, it works. But I'm using SQL Query, and I want to use the built in commands of the MySQL Connector/C++ Dev API to create a table, if the table not exist.

As you can see, there is only one method inside the class that begins with the word "create".

[image]

How can I create a table with this library in the proper way?